# How can I communicate an Android Accessory with a USB Serial Port?

Tags: android, usb, accessory

**Hereby the situation:** I'm working on a *Android* Tablet that **must** work in [Accessory](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory.html) mode. Reason why is because the tablet can't provide enough power to perform the communication with a Serial USB microcontroller and remain charging it's battery.

[image]

In order to achieve a successful communication, I must be able to set a few serial conditions for `Modbus/RTU`

- Serial Port Address (i.e. COM1, COM2...)
- Baud Rate (19200 bps)
- Data Bits (8)
- Stop Bits (1)
- Parity (None)

> An excellent example in Delphi would be [Modlink](http://www.ozm.cz/ivobauer/modlink/introduction.htm).
>
> A good guidance would be UART https://github.com/ytai/ioio/wiki/UART

Meanwhile, I've found some useful projects but they were intended to work on **Host** mode.

> https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android
> https://github.com/ksksue/Android-USB-Serial-Monitor-Lite

I'm looking for any valuable information, guidance and references on how should I proceed to create an Android Application that can communicate with Serial USB.

How can I achieve this?

Note: I'm using `Android Studio`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an excellent source code made by FTDI Chip, so if you ever need to perform USB/ftdi connections with Android try this application:

[FTDI UART TERMINAL](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ftdi.j2xx.hyperterm)

> Source code: http://www.ftdichip.com/Android.htm