# C# SerialPort with Java Android phone

Tags: c#, android

what i'm trying to do:

- Create an App for windows to connect android phone.
- Send and receive data.
- Windows (C#) is the host device --> android UsbAccessory.

C#:

[image: As you can see, the COM5 is my Android phone]

now i can select the COM5 (Android phone) and connect to it, using this code:

```
   serialPort1.PortName = this.devicesList.Text; // COM5
   serialPort1.Open();
   addToList("SerialPort is opened", Color.Green);
```

Java (Android Phone):

```java
     UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
     UsbAccessory[] accessories = manager.getAccessoryList();
```

`accessories` is Always Null, i tried every code i find, but i could not do it.

what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

::: EDIT :::

Android Studio Code (Java)

```
package com.example.camerausb;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbAccessory;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class UsbConnector extends Activity {
    private static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "com.example.camerausb.UsbConnector.USB_PERMISSION";
    public UsbManager usbManager;
    public UsbAccessory usbAccessory;
    public PendingIntent mPermissionIntent;
    public Context global_context;
    private IntentFilter filter;
    
    private final BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(action)) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    UsbAccessory accessory = (UsbAccessory) intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_ACCESSORY);
                    if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
                        Toast.makeText(global_context, "Allow Usb Permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        // TODO:: open Accessory method
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(global_context, "Deny Usb Permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_DETACHED.equals(action)) {
                Toast.makeText(global_context, "Usb detached", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(global_context, "something else", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    };

    public UsbConnector(Context context) {
        super();
        global_context = context;
        Toast.makeText(global_context, "started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        usbManager = (UsbManager) global_context.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
        mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(global_context, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
        filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
        filter.addAction(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
        
      filter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_DETACHED);
      usbManager.requestPermission(usbAccessory, mPermissionIntent);
        global_context.registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, filter);
    }

    public BroadcastReceiver getReceiver() {
        return this.mUsbReceiver;
    }
    public IntentFilter getFilter() {
        return this.filter;
    }

    public void resumeAccessory(Intent intent) {
//        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Toast.makeText(global_context, "resume: " + action, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        UsbAccessory[] accessories = usbManager.getAccessoryList();
        if (accessories != null) {
            Toast.makeText(global_context, "Accessory not NULL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(global_context, "Accessory is NULL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
}
```

Manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.camerausb">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="12" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.accessory" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.CameraUsb">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED"
                android:resource="@xml/accessory_filter" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

xml/accessory_filter :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>
    <usb-accessory model="DemoKit" manufacturer="Google" version="1.0" />
</resources>
```

Comment: From the docs " The result will be empty if no devices are attached, or if USB host mode is inactive or unsupported. Requires the PackageManager#FEATURE_USB_HOST feature which can be detected using PackageManager.hasSystemFeature(String)."

Comment: And that would be an Android question specifically. There is nothing in it related to Java as such, really.

Comment: @Fildor sorry for that - the highlights of the code is gone!,

Comment: I was only talking about the tags. For Code highlighting, "Java" is ok, I believe.

Comment: Related: [How can I communicate an Android Accessory with a USB Serial Port?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28299723/295004)

Comment: @MorrisonChang Thanks, i'm checking the source codes

Comment: @MorrisonChang i think the problem with the broadcastReceiver object, not firing

Comment: @MorrisonChang i could not do it man, if u found some example ( new example ) please send it, Thanls.

Comment: Honestly you should edit your post to include details of what you tried, what you are changing (I can't tell if your windows app needs the fix or the Android side), how you tested (i.e. tested Windows side with an Android app from the Play Store or F-Droid or with a USB serial device). And show code if possible.

Comment: @MorrisonChang i added the android code, with manifest and xml/filter .. forgive me man i had no education in programming, what i'm trying to do with this app, is sending the camera data to program in windows, i dont want to use sockets over network, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

someone told me to add `usbManager.requestPermission(usbAccessory, mPermissionIntent);`

the phone screen goes to black and luck it self!!